# Solve : $(2x+3)^3y'''+3(2x+3)y'-6y=6x(x+3), x>\frac{3}{2}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Solve :

$(2x+3)^3y'''+3(2x+3)y'-6y=6x(x+3), x>\frac{3}{2}$

I know how to solve this ode using  power series method, I am looking for another method.

An explanation how to solve it using another method is welcome.

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

First, you only should care for the solution to the homogeneous ODE and let me write it this way: $$(2x+3)^3 y''' + 3(2x+3)^1 y' -6(2x+3)^0 y=0$$ because the powers of the coefficients match the order of the  derivatives. So it suggests a change of variables: $2x+3=u$

Now we want $y=y(x) \, \xrightarrow[]{} y(u(x))$ and the derivatives in terms of $u$. Using chain rule:

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{dy}{du} \, \frac{du}{dx} = 2 \frac{dy}{du}$$

$$ \frac{d^2y}{dx^2} = 2\frac{d}{dx} \left( \frac{dy}{du}\right) = 2 \frac{d^2 y}{du^2} \frac{du}{dx} = 4 \frac{d^2 y}{du^2}$$

$$\frac{d^3y}{dx^3} = 4 \frac{d}{dx} \left( \frac{d^2y}{du^2}\right) = 4 \frac{d^3 y}{du^3} \frac{du}{dx} = 8 \frac{d^3 y}{du^3}$$

Now rewrite the ODE in the new variable
$$8u^3 y'''(u) +6u y'(u)-6y(u)=0 $$
Its a third order Euler Cauchy ODE, and it has this characteristic polynomial:$$8m(m-1)(m-2)+6m-6=0$$
that reduces to
$$8m^3-24m^2+22m-6=0$$
and its solutions are $m_1=1/2$,  $m_2=1$,  $m_3=3/2$.

The solutions of the polynomial are the powers of the linearly-independent functions of the form $u^m$, so the homogeneus solutions is:

$$y(u)=c_1 \; u^{1/2} + c_2 \; u + c_3 \; u^{3/2} \;\; ; c_1, c_2, c_3 \in \mathbb{R}$$

Change variables again:

$$y(x)=c_1 \; (2x+3)^{1/2} + c_2 \; (2x+3) + c_3 \; (2x+3)^{3/2} \;\; ; c_1, c_2, c_3 \in \mathbb{R}$$

And you're basically done! For the solution to the non-homogeneous, you can use Lagrange method since you have three linearly-independant solutions to the homogeneous ODE. Lagrange always works, perhaps you could propose a complete second degree polynomial first and check if it works, if not, Lagrange it is.

Comment: Thanks ! there is a generic method for sloving $p(x)y''+q(x)y'+g(x)y=0$ except  power series method?

Comment: Sadly, no, there's no generic method! That's why function coefficients ODE are so much harder comapred to constant coefficients. To derive generic methods you have to impose conditions for $p(x)$, $q(x)$, $g(x)$, such as the Euler-Cauchy equations do.